# Можно ли сделать свой чат на хостинге?

Tags: чат, хостинг

Привет. Есть ли какие-нибудь техники, чтобы на обычном хостинге сделать свой чат с мгновенной отправкой и получением сообщений? Ведь polling и long poll требуют больших ресурсов, которые хостинги не дают.

UPD: можно поставить вопрос по другому — имеются хостинг (timeweb) и желание сделать чат с мгновенной отправкой и получением сообщений. Это реально?

Comment: Сейчас в моде websockets, у которых на все подключения один процесс и, как правило, одно подключение к БД. Можно ли это развернуть на shared-хостинге - зависит от хостера, сервера уже написаны практически на всех языках.

Comment: @Fike это которые небезопасные, и отключены по умолчанию в браузерах?

Comment: Попробуйте [на heroku развернуть node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) приложение. В режиме разработки, без нагрузки, раньше можно было оставаться в рамках бесплатной квоты.

Comment: @Dazar, это которые включены.

Comment: @Fike, можно ссылочку на описание?

Comment: [Докумемтация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/WebSockets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хостинги - они разные бывают. Но большинство такие вещи не одобряет, проверено... 
Поэтому самый верный путь - это VPS за 5-10 долларов и развернутый на нем node.js с модулями поддержки вебсокетов (sockjs,soket.io)

Comment: Можно пару ссылок на 5-10 долларовые VPS?

Comment: http://infobox.ru/vps/linux/ http://digitalocean.com http://lowendbox.com/

Comment: во-во, я сам на лоуэндбоксе пасусь, очень выгодно.